# neo4j-admin command is not found when importing files using import tool

Tags: neo4j

I am trying to import nodes and relationship into neo4j graphDB using neo4j import tool. so far I have written a script import.sh and it looks as document follows

```
neo4j-admin import \
--id-type=string \
--nodes:AGENT="import/nodes_1.csv,import/nodes_2.csv" \
--nodes:CUSTOMER="import/nodes_C1.csv,import/nodes_CUSTOMER_C2.csv" \
--relationship:related="import/rel_HEADER.csv,import/rel_test.csv"
```

I can run my neo4j service from console by `./bin/neo4j console`

when I am running my script ./import.sh  I am getting 
**./import.sh: line 1: neo4j-admin: command not found**
I am running neo4j 3.5.6 community edition in MacOS . Am I missing something here .  kindly help me to sort it out

Answer (score 2):

The error is telling you that your computer doesn't know what you mean by `neo4j-admin`. You need to tell it where this program is located.

If I had to guess, you need to replace `neo4j-admin` with `./bin/neo4j-admin` in your command.